# Sublime Text custom build system with command line

Tags: python, sublimetext

Does anyone have some experience with custom build systems in Sublime Text 3, especially with python as a base?

At the moment I struggle here with the problem that a extern command line program should be called for baking the file of user.

My current ".sublime-build" looks like this:

```
{
    "target": "convert2libpart",
    "selector": "text.xml.gdl"
}
```

The target is set to the python file,
which is this:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import os, os.path
from subprocess import call

# convert the current XML to binary via
# the converter -> who does actual work

class convert2libpart(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, cmd="", file_regex="", path=""):

        view = self.window.active_view()

        self.plat = sublime.platform()

        # get the settings
        s = sublime.load_settings("somesettings.sublime-settings")
        version = s.get("version") # this is from a settingsfile, as you can see
        version = str(version)

        if self.plat == "windows":
            converter_path = "C:\\Program Files\\folder " + version + "\\"
        #else:
            # osx path... (program is available on both systems)


        file_name = os.path.basename(view.file_name())
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(view.file_name())
        # XMLConverter xml2libpart source dest
        cmd = "XMLConverter.exe xml2libpart " + "\"" + dir_path + "\\" + file_name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + dir_path + "output" + "\""


        proc = call("start cmd /K " + cmd, cwd=converter_path, shell=True)
```

If I use this build system I can see in the task manager that the converter will start, but the output is not generated. Is it the program's fault?
Doing this manually with exact same command will produce the desired output.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.